# After this exception occurs all other requests are failing "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

Tags: java, hibernate

After this exception occurs all other requests are failing - "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session".

> - javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.dventus.common.user.User#rp_test_user1]
>     2019-03-21 10:56:44,370 19749 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] INFO  com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@7fc183ea: calling rollback...
>     2019-03-21 10:56:44,370 19749 [http-nio-8080-exec-24] INFO  com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy  - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@7fc183ea: calling setAutoCommit...

Code to add my entity:

```java
public MDMResponse process(MDMRequest mdmRequest)  throws Exception {
    MDMResponse mdmResponse = null;
    AddProcessor.logger.info("\n Request recieved "+mdmRequest.toString());
    final EntityManager entityManager = this.getContext().getEntityManager();
    try {
        final Object entity = this.getContext().getMapper().toEntity(mdmRequest);
        AddProcessor.logger.debug("The entity found is "+entity.getClass().getName());
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        mdmResponse = new MDMResponse(ResponseStatus.OK, Messages.SAVE_SUCCESS);
        AddProcessor.logger.debug(mdmResponse.toString());
    }

    catch (final Exception e) {
        AddProcessor.logger.error(e);
        mdmResponse = new MDMErrorResponse(ResponseStatus.ERROR, Messages.SAVE_ERROR,Catagory.SAVE,Code.ONE,Severity.normal);
    }

    return mdmResponse;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code which you are using.

Comment: Provide the id sequence generator you are using

Comment: are you saying how i generate the primary key

Comment: @yoseSe Yes, exactly.

Comment: the primary key is one of my object  that i include with the request so i set it manually,  within insert operation as a variable .

Comment: @yoseSe That's a bad idea. The id-generation process should not be handled manually, exactly because of the issues you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after catch and check

```
    finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

Comment: it start to return:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active